# A better way to change 2 <div>s classes upon radio button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make a form where the user selects a color from a variety of options in as radio inputs. And upon selecting his/her option 2 other elements have classes added or substracted to them.

I managed to hack a way using VALUE and ID matched to class names.

Value changes one DIV, and ID changes the other.

It works, however it seems like a very hacky and unelegant way to do it. What if i need a 3rd element affected in the future?

Here is my jquery code:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $('#preview').attr('class', 'obj').addClass(this.value)
    $('#ttc').attr('class', '.clr-span').addClass(this.id)
  });
```

[Here is the jfiddle of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/ung99hxm/133/)

Thanks in advance for your time,

Comment: Here's a different solution using JS objects to store the various styles: http://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/a3vwkjcn/ You can extend this arbitrarily.

Comment: don't sweat too much on such trivial things.. make it work and forget about it unless this is part of a huge app and you are looking for performance/code readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5 you can add arbitrary attributes to your elements. So you can do something like this:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() 
    let $this = $(this);
    $('#preview').attr('class', 'obj').addClass($this.data('a'))
    $('#ttc').attr('class', 'clr-span').addClass($this.data('b'))
  });
```

Edit: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xed47rr6/8/)

Edit2: Note that you don't need the `.` in `.clr-span` when using `attr()`

Comment: `.attr('class', '.clr-span')` seems mistake from OP, maybe you should correct it.

Comment: I assumed this was to reset the class attribute before adding new classes. Not a good implementation but outside the scope of the question

Comment: cool.. maybe add a note in answer for OP.. few tips along the way is nice IMO

Comment: Thanks! This works great.
Do you think removing the     .attr(,) would be possible with a toggleClass instead of add Class?

Comment: @barcelok You would need to toggle off all the possible classes that could be applied every time, so it would not scale. I recommend replacing the className attribute completely like I've done in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xed47rr6/22/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 custom `data-*` attributes to achieve this.

In the example below, I have used:

- `data-preview-background-color`
- `data-background-color`
- `data-color`

You can access the values of these attributes by camel-casing the hyphenated names, like this:

- `element.dataset.previewBackgroundColor`
- `element.dataset.backgroundColor`
- `element.dataset.color`

**Working Example:**

```js
var preview = document.getElementsByClassName('preview')[0];
var previewParagraph = preview.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]; 
var colourSelectors = document.querySelectorAll('[name="SelectColour"]');

function changeColours() {
    preview.style.backgroundColor = this.dataset.previewBackgroundColor;
    previewParagraph.style.backgroundColor = this.dataset.backgroundColor;
    previewParagraph.style.color = this.dataset.color;
}

for (var i = 0; i < colourSelectors.length; i++) {

    colourSelectors[i].addEventListener('change', changeColours, false);
}
```

```css
.preview {
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.preview p {
height: 48px;
line-height: 48px;
margin: 24px 0;
}

.preview {
border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">
<p>Change this text</p>
</div>

<form>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="SelectColour" data-preview-background-color="white" data-background-color="green" data-color="red">White
</label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="SelectColour" data-preview-background-color="gray" data-background-color="black" data-color="white">Gray
</label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="SelectColour" data-preview-background-color="red" data-background-color="pink" data-color="orangered">Cherry Red
</label>

</form>
```